# Python 3.5 not letting me pip install certain libraries

Tags: pip, setup.py, python-3.5, egg

So I recently upgraded from python 3.4 to 3.5 on my macbook pro.  Now when I try to pip install certain libraries I keep getting this error.  I have searched and searched and haven't found a solution. Has anyone else had this issue and solved it???

```
   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/1_/vjkc260x25v12hl0d3nrqqwc0000gn/T
```

Comment: Did you run the command as super user using `sudo`? Which version Mac OS X are you using?

Comment: I am using version 10.10.4 (14E46).  I haven't had to use sudo before on my mac to use pip.  I will try though.